# How to perform authentication in QuickBooks Online in installed app (NOT a web app)?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Let's say I have an installed app, a console app for example, not a web app, that I want to interact with the QBO API - I want to perform calls to QBO from my console app (but not from a web application). So I must authenticate from the console app, make a call and output in the console.

All QBO SDKs seem to ask for a callback URL or a redirect URL, i.e. a page on my server, that will perform the required leg of the [OAuth 2.0](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/10_authentication_and_authorization/10_oauth_2.0) authentication. As my installed app is not a webserver, I don't have a place to host this logic. Yes, I can host a webserver to handle this logic, but I don't want to do it, this is a waste of resources for my use case (why leave an auth server on standby?). I just want to authenticate without a webserver with QBO API. Is this possible? Have I messed up my understanding of the API or of OAuth? I am at a total loss. In none of the sample code I can find a suitable example despite this being the use case that I have. (I am working with .NET / C#)

Comment: Are you using the OAuth 1.x or OAuth 2.0?

Comment: I am on OAuth 2.0 simply because there seems to be a requirement that all new apps must use this. I don't care about authentication method at all at the end of the day, so long as I can authenticate without callback url.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that at the moment the QuickBooks Developer platform will not accommodate this (non web End-Point).

As per Intuit:

> These URIs handle responses from the OAuth 2.0 server and are called
>   after the user authorizes the connection. URIs in this list are the
>   only ones to which the authorization response can be sent from the
>   OAuth 2.0 server.   You must define at least one URI specifically for
>   your application's auth endpoint before you can use OAuth 2.0.

Additionally they add in a note:

> Mobile- or desktop-based apps that implement OAuth 2.0 must provide a
>   separate SaaS layer for the Redirect URI to handle responses from the
>   OAuth 2.0 server.

I realize this is not what you had hoped for.  Please understand, however,  understand that the end-point must be a URL so as to securely return the authentication token.